# Does NLTK have just a list of emotive/sentiment words?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm looking to try and improve my first ever machine learning attempt.

At the moment, I've been getting a good ~90% for my tweet data, using the entire word list as my feature list

I would like to filter out this feature list so it only includes relevant words to gauge sentiment (i.e. words like good,bad,happy,     and not robot/car/technology)

Anyone have some advice?

I've made use of their stop words, but then for this, non-sentiment words like "technology" aren't really stopwords

My main approach is to just filter out manually all the words i think wont help, although this assumes I will always use the same input data

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind is [AFINN list](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=6010), have you run across it? It's a list of English words rated for valence with an integer between minus five (negative) and plus five (positive), created specifically for microblogs. Quick serach for AFINN on Google also spits out a lot of interesting resources.